# Why should the destructor of base classes be virtual?

Tags: c++, inheritance

in C++: Why should the destructor of base classes be virtual?

Answer (score 37):

The better question is *when and why*. Your question indicates that you think all base classes should have virtual destructors, which is not quite true.

It would make it impossible to apply the empty base class optimization, and could multiply the size of classes up to 16 times than what it would be without `virtual` on common platforms.

A `virtual` destructor is needed when you `delete` an object whose dynamic type is `DerivedClass` by a pointer that has type `BaseClass*`. The `virtual` makes the compiler associate information in the object making it able to execute the derived class destructor. Missing the `virtual` in such case causes undefined behavior.

If you don't need this, and your class is only used as a base class, it's best to make the destructor `protected`, thus preventing that users accidentally `delete` in the described way.

Comment: For another excellent description, see [*Virtuality*](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm), specifically, "Guideline #4: A base class destructor should be either public and virtual, or protected and nonvirtual."

Answer (score 8):

You want them to be virtual so that all subclass destructors are automatically called when the object is destroyed, even if it is destroyed through a pointer to the base class. In the following code:

```
class base {
public:
  virtual ~base() { }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
  ~derived() { }  // Inherits the virtual designation
};

int main(void)
{
  base *b = new derived;

  delete b;
}
```

The derived destructor will *only* be called if the base destructor is virtual.

As Magnus indicates, you don't have to do this if you aren't taking advantage of polymorphism. However, I try to develop the habit of declaring all my destructors virtual. It protects me against the case where I should have declared them virtual but forget to do so. As Johannes indicates, this habit can impose a small space and performance penalty when the virtual designation is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

They dont have to be virtual unless you are using polymorphism. If you do use polymorphism they need to be virtual so that the destructors of inherited classes are guaranteed to be called, so inherited classes can do their clean up.

Answer (score 4):

For situations like this:

```
class A
{
    virtual ~A();
};

class B:A
{
    ~B();
};

A *a = new B(); //legal, since it's a downcast
delete a; //Unless the destructor is virtual, ~A() is called here instead of ~B().
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be virtual to ensure that the destructor of the inherited classes are the ones actually getting called at runtime instead of the base class destructor being called.