# I cannot understand how a struct can substitute a typedef

Tags: c++, c++14

See this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C4503)&rd=true It suggests to write:

```
// C4503b.cpp  
// compile with: /W1 /EHsc /c  
#include <string>  
#include <map>  

class Field{};  
struct Screen2 {  
   std::map<std::string, Field> Element;  
};  

struct WebApp2 {  
   std::map<std::string, Screen2> Element;  
};  

struct WebAppTest2 {  
   std::map<std::string, WebApp2> Element;  
};  

struct Hello2 {  
   std::map<std::string, WebAppTest2> Element;  
};  

Hello2 MyWAT2;
```

instead of

```
// C4503.cpp  
// compile with: /W1 /EHsc /c  
// C4503 expected  
#include <string>  
#include <map>  

class Field{};  

typedef std::map<std::string, Field> Screen;  
typedef std::map<std::string, Screen> WebApp;  
typedef std::map<std::string, WebApp> WebAppTest;  
typedef std::map<std::string, WebAppTest> Hello;  
Hello MyWAT;
```

But those codes are not equivalent as with the typedefs `Hello` is an `std::map` while with `struct`s it is just a struct that has a field which is a `map` which means I cannot use them interchangeably. Could someone explain the trick?

Comment: There is no trick. You'll have to add `.Element`s to your code.

Comment: Isn't that link just a suggestion to workaround the issue of the decorated name being longer than the compiler limit rather than suggesting that this is an interchangeable usage?

Comment: "You might, however, decide to not restructure your code.", that suggests to me that there's no trick implied, it's literally just suggesting to wrap your maps up in structs.

Comment: Use clang :-P = http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ef55ab12b979785

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, you can't use them interchangeably. In fact, Microsoft advise you to do so in order to overcome a technical difficulty from their end: they can't (or have difficulty to) handle mangled names longer than 4096 bytes.

In most case, a `typedef` would be a better solution over aggregation, I believe.

But since your compiler is somewhat limited, you may be stuck with their hack.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution which fulfills the goal of differentiating the (mangled, possibly truncated) names, but without the downside of an extra layer of naming, you can use inheritance:

```
class Screen : public std::map<std::string, Field>
{
    // forward constructors here
};
```

Comment: beware `std::map::~map()` is not `virtual`

Comment: @YSC Actually, it only means that you should not allocate any resources which need to be freed in the wrapper class. `map<std::string, Field> *mp = new Screen(); delete mp;` works just fine. Or am I mistaken? (My second thoughts came with the idea of deeper inheritance hierarchies, multiple inheritance etc. Could there be memory de-allocation issues or would the raw memory always be handled properly?)

Comment: I agree, this is just something to be aware of. I upvoted your answer since this is surely the best workaround. And multiple-layer wrappers should be fine unless you have a non-trivial destructor for them.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider "Or am I mistaken" you are in theory but not in practice.  In theory, compilers could put extra padding into the Screen() class, which wouldn't be freed in your example.  In practice, they don't.

Comment: @UKMonkey: In practice `delete` calls `free()` which remembers the size to deallocate based on internal bookkeeping, rather than type information.  So even if padding were present it wouldn't be a problem.  You could even add some POD fields in `Screen` and it would be fine in practice, because POD types don't need to be destroyed, only deallocated.

Comment: @UKMonkey I just wanted to ask a question about it but of course it has been answered before, http://stackoverflow.com/a/9909559/3150802. Deleting through base pointer requires a dynamic dtor, or UB. (John's remark notwithstanding: I'd be surprised if simple cases like the trivial one here cause problems. But of course allocators exist which put objects of different sizes in different arenas, and poof.)

Answer (score 0):

The *workaround* provided isn't to be meant as an equivalent replacement of the reproducer but rather as a *possible* way to reduce the decorated length of exported symbols.

You can verify with a simple `objdump /symbols objfile.obj` that the length of decorated symbols by using `typedef`s is incredibly longer than their similar counterparts split into `struct`s (Microsoft compilers have historically used a proprietary name mangling scheme).

Answer (score 0):

A `typedef` doesn't declare a new type, it just an alias. And if you forward-declare a `typedef`, when the compiler sees the `typedef` definition, it throws you an error:

```
// a.hpp
class Screen;

class any_class_using_screen {};

// a.cpp
#include "a.hpp"

typedef std::map<std::string, Field> Screen; // Error.
```

Using even simple inheritance allows you to use your custom names for other types:

```
class Screen : public std::map<std::string, Field>
{};
```

Remeber that simple inheritance without additional members doesn't cause any memory or time overhead. That is as efficient as a `typedef`, with the adventage that it is a new type.

Since `std::map<...>` hasn't virtual destructors, you cannot use the "pointer to base class" pattern as usual, of course. The owner of the `Screen` instance (the one who created a `screen` instance), if it lives in the heap and must be destructed, must be destructed from a pointer to the derived class:

```
template<class K, class V>
void f(std::map<K, V> const* map); // Do something

int main()
{
    Screen* s = new Screen;
    f(s); // Ok
    delete s; // OK, deleting from derivate class
}
```

@PeterA.Scheneider suggest that, as far as the derivate class hasn't additional members, nothing happens, and you can call the destructor from a pointer to the derived class. But, `theoretically`, without a virtual destructor, you are destructing the base class instance (only the base class life reachs to its end), and the derivate class instance is still alive with a dead base, having a corrupted object. From a practical point of view, I think the object is correctly destructed, but anyway I don't know if that can cause undefined behaviour.

The standard should be check to be sure.

Additionally, there could be alignment issues with that approach of destructing, from a base class pointer, a derivated object without extra members.

If a base class has no virtual destructor, do inheritance without "polymorphic intentions", and destruct always from the most derived class.