# How to expose inherited constructors when using nested templating?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++20, class-template

Consider this simple class derived from `std::variant`:

```
#include <string>
#include <variant>

class my_variant : public std::variant<int, std::string>
{
    using variant::variant;
public:
    std::string foo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

Notice, I am deliberately adding `using variant:variant` so that constructors from the base class are exposed in the derived class. If you do not do this, instances of `my_variant` class will not work with `operator=`  without a bunch of re-definitions.
This compiles just fine.

---

Now let's start turning it into a template step-by-step.

```
template <typename TChr>
class my_variant : public std::variant<int, std::string>
{
    using variant::variant;

public:
    // Changed to templated return type, compiles fine
    std::basic_string<TChr> foo() 
    {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

Here, the only change is that we make use of the template parameter in the `foo()` method. Everything still compiles fine.

And now this:

```
template <typename TChr>
class my_variant : // Changed to templated base class
    public std::variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>> 
{
    // Now this line won't compile !!
    using variant::variant; 

public:
    std::basic_string<TChr> foo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

As soon as I make use of the template parameter to describe the base class, I am getting the following compiler error:

```
'variant': is not a class or namespace name
```

for this line: `using variant::variant;`

I do not fully understand why this specific change causes a problem. So far I was thinking in the direction that maybe `using variant::variant` without specifying its template signature is a problem, so I tried this:

```
template <typename TChr>
class my_variant :
    public std::variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>>
{
    // Added templating here, still fails with the same error message.
    using variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>>::variant; 

public:
    std::basic_string<TChr> foo()
    {
        return "";
    }
};
```

Doing so generates the same error message, so I must be doing something wrong.

Compiler is MSVC 2022, C++20 mode.

Comment: Deriving from std::variant is not really suppored it's [destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/~variant) is not virtual AND it has not virtual methods.  Looks like you're better of aggregating a variant in you own class. Also look at this answe [inheriting from classes without virtual destructor (and methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909439/inheriting-from-classes-without-virtual-destructors). Anyway I do not recommend using inheritance if the only reason is code reuse.

Comment: not saying that this is a moot question, but I'd argue that inheriting from `std::variant` isnt the best idea to begin with. I mean one main motivation for `std::variant` is as alternative to inheritance. In a nutshell, dont inherit, but visit!

Comment: @PepijnKramer deriving from non virtual classes works fine, so long as you don't treat it like Java.  C++ inheritance interacts with template agument deduction in.ways that cannot be reproduced via other techniques

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I know it can work (give or take a few caveats). But the fact that it can work is not the same as recommended or good practice.  (overuse of) Inheritance has a tendency to result in too tightly coupled software  that is almost impossible to refactor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] So I must be doing something wrong!!

Since in the last  `my_variant`, the parent `std::variant` depends upon the class template argument, you also need the constructor from the correct parent

```
template <typename TChr>
class my_variant : public std::variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>> 
{
    using std::variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>>::variant;
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
public:
    std::basic_string<TChr> foo()
    {
        return "foo";
    }
};
```

---

That has been mentioned, also have a read here, for more about your approach:

[Is it okay to inherit implementation from STL containers, rather than delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate)

Comment: Thank you, specifying std namespace in front of variant::variant indeed eliminated the problem. Curiously, if I do the same for the first and second examples (those that were compiling fine), they won't compile now. And yes, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on JeJo's answer:

The key idea here is *name lookup.* Whenever you use a name in C++, the compiler must decide what entity that name refers to. Sometimes it can just look for a declaration in the current scope (or one of its parents), e.g.

```
void foo() { return foo(); }
                    ^~~
```

There's no `foo` declared in the current scope, but there's the function named `foo` in the parent scope, so we take that.

Inside a class or class template, another possibility kicks in: the [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

```
int Foo = 42;
struct Foo {
    void f(Foo&);
           ^~~
```

Here, the name `Foo` means "this class right here, `Foo`," even though there are multiple declarations of a name `Foo` in the parent scope. (C++ allows you to have a type and a variable with the same name at namespace scope, because C compatibility: think [`stat(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stat).) We call this the *injected-class-name* of `Foo`.

Injected-class-names also apply to base classes:

```
int Base = 42;
struct Base {};
struct Foo : Base {
    void f(Base&);
           ^~~~
```

There's no `Base` in the current scope, so we look in the parent scope, which is the base-class scope. There *is* a `Base` in that scope: the *injected-class-name* that means "this `Base` right here." So this code is also okay.

Inside a class template, the *injected-class-name* refers to "this *instantiation* of `Foo` right here." So:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo {
    void f(Foo&);
           ^~~
```

this `Foo` means the same thing as if it had said `Foo<T>`.

But remember, all of this is a subsystem of *name lookup*. The other relevant quirk of name lookup is that during phase 1 of [two-phase lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/two-phase_lookup) (that is, before template instantiation), name lookup never peeks into dependent base classes. (It can't, because they're dependent on template arguments, and we don't know those arguments yet.) So ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T1EzncMe9)):

```
template<class T>
struct Foo : NDBase<int>, DBase<T> {
    void f(NDBase&, DBase&);
           ^~~~~~   ^~~~~
```

The reference to `NDBase` is OK: that's the *injected-class-name* of `NDBase<int>` inherited from `NDBase<int>`. The reference to `DBase` is bad: that's *not* the *injected-class-name* of `DBase<T>`, because `DBase<T>` is a dependent base, so `Foo` isn't going to look up anything in it.

We can tell name lookup that `DBase` is supposed to be looked up as a member by prefixing it with `Foo::` (for most kinds of members, prefer `this->`). Of course then we also need to tell the parser that this dependent name is going to be a typename, not a variable/function/etc.:

```
template<class T>
struct Foo : NDBase<int>, DBase<T> {
    void f(NDBase&, typename Foo::DBase&); // OK
};
```

In your original example, you can get away without the `typename` prefix because `using ...` is already a typename-only context. In other words, you can do either:

```
using my_variant::variant::variant;
  // express that `variant` is a member, so look it up in
  // the dependent base and find it as an injected-class-name

using std::variant<int, std::basic_string<TChr>>::variant;
  // avoid injected-class-names entirely, and just name the
  // base type relative to the parent scope
```

But you can't just say

```
using variant::~~~~
```

because the compiler doesn't know what `variant` means in this scope. (Because it refuses to peek into the dependent base class in order to find that there's a matching *injected-class-name* visible in there.)